# Is it possible to get simulator target name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator

When we are running app in simulator ,we add our simulators as iPhone e.g. iPhone 6,iPhone 5s etc.. Is it possible to now the simulator name specifically??

when I searched  , I got to know whether it is iPhone or iPad and also the deceives which is connected to the system

Do anyone suggest me if it is possible to find??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may check architecture using `#if (arch(i386) || arch(x86_64))` (currently all the iDevices work on ARM processors, and simulators work on x86-compatibles) to be sure that's a simulator and then use [`(UI)Device.current(Device).model`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidevice/1620044-model) inside `#if/#endif`.

This property returns model of current device.

EDIT: `Objective C`

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    … [[UIDevice currentDevice] model] … // Do something with result here
#endif
```

Comment: can you help me using objective c?

Comment: Im new to IOS..actually where should i write this code??

Comment: ERROR    :Token is not a valid binary operator in a preprocessor subexpression